# Remove playlist from Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, playlists

As the title says, I want to remove a playlist from Rhythymbox but I can't seem to find an option to do so. When I right-click said playlist nothing happens and from the Edit menu I have no options to remove it either. (see screenshot)

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Left click on the play list to give it focus.

Then click the <kbd>-</kbd> button on the left-bottom of the screen.

Comment: I edited my question to add more info, please read it.

Comment: @LucyC I edited my answer based on your new question edits.

Comment: That worked! Thanks :D Can't believe I never noticed that button before.

Comment: @LucyC I can't believe the Gnome instructions I quoted last time were sooo wrong on their website!

Comment: This is astonishing that they did not include the delete option in the context menu.

Comment: Even more amazing is how absolutely unintuitive that is. Bad UI design. I was looking to do this today and found this answer. Upon reading, I realized I stumbled upon the secret sauce before. The fact that people struggle just shows how myopic developers can be - and I know, for I am one!

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to bulk delete:  I seem unable to select more than one and  when I delete one, `Music` is selected (!) and I have to click on the next playlist and delete it - lather, rinse, repeat. If there is no other way to do it, that is awful! I hope I missed an easier way.